# How can I store an array of ResultSet's each ResultSet rows in a single ResultSet?

Tags: java, arrays, jdbc

This is a bit strange problem but I have an **array of ResultSet** of which each ResultSet contains different number of rows. Now I require to store all those rows stored in each ResultSet of the array as a **single ResultSet.**
This is required so as I need to sort all those rows according to the TIMESTAMP stored in those rows column.

Is there any possible way to implement such a logic?

Comment: It seems that you don't understand what you really want

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood that correctly... You have a `ResultSet[]`, where `ResultSet` probably implements `java.util.Set`, and you want to merge them into one. On top of that, you want to sort them by some timestamp, or what?

Comment: @Cedric : yes I need to merge them into one.

Comment: It sounds to me like you don't know how to write proper SQL.  You should be able to write a single query to return all that data and ORDER BY all at once.

Answer (score 2):

You should *not* do this.

`ResultSet` should be mapped into objects or data structures and closed in the scope of the method in which they were created.  You are free to merge those data structures into a single one to return to clients for consumption.

The reason this is such a bad idea is `ResultSet` represents a cursor on the database server side.  If you don't close them in the query method they won't be closed on the server side.  Users won't have clear responsibility for cleaning them up.  Eventually you'll exhaust the pool of database cursors and your app will crash.